# How to import complete csv into Microsoft Access database using JAVA in Eclipse

Tags: java, database

I am on inetrn at DAIKIN JAPAN

I am writing code in JAVA in ECLIPSE... and I have to use Microsoft Access database  for some data analyzing.....

I want to know the query to import whole csv file into my database..?????

Answer (score 0):

Use [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) to read content of CSV file . Create insert query and process your csv content to database.

How to read - [link](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#how-to-read)